# Simple elimination in a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Apologies if the question is too simple for the website.
I am trying to show that:  $$2b-a=4$$
in this system of equations (it's part of a longer question that is unimportant to mention):
$$a(1-λ)-2λ=-6$$
$$-2b(1-λ)-2λ=2$$
I intentionally ordered them that way in order to perform an elimination and obtain the final result. But I am unsure how to eliminate $(1-\lambda)$. I know I could perform a simple substitution of  $λ=\frac{6+a}{a+2}$ but I would like to know if elimination is possible in that case; would adding the two equations cross the two brackets out?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You want to solve for $a$ and $b$, and not for $\lambda$. So express $a$ and $b$ by $\lambda$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite this as $$\begin{cases}
(1-\lambda)(a+2)=-4 \\ 
(1-\lambda)(2-2b)=4 
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that (multiply first equation by $(2-2b)$, second by $(a+2)$ and subtract) $$4(2-2b)+4(a+2)=0 \implies 4-2b+a=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\lambda=1$ gives a contradiction, we can conclude that
$a=\frac{2\lambda -6}{1-\lambda}$ and $b=-\frac{1+\lambda}{1-\lambda}$. So we have
$$
2b-a=\frac{-2-2\lambda+6-2\lambda}{1-\lambda}=4.
$$